# Issue creating repository github v3 api via Java

Tags: java, github-api, scribe

I'm trying to send a post request to github to create a repository. I've got oauth 2.0 working and the request is correctly signed but github is just returning "Problems parsing JSON"

I'm using Scribe for the oauth side of things and as far as I can tell I've added JSON to the URL but I'm not 100% certain I'm doing it correctly, or am I just missing headers or something?

```
@POST
@Path("create_repo/{userid}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createRepo(@PathParam("userid") String userid) {

    OAuthService service = createService().build();
    User user = collection.findOneById(userid);

    final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://api.github.com/user/repos", service);

    Token token = new Token(user.getGithubToken(), "SECRET");
    service.signRequest(token, request);

    request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    request.addHeader("X-OAuth-Scopes", "repo");
    request.addQuerystringParameter("name", "Test_v1");

    LOGGER.info("Built request: " + request.getCompleteUrl());

    final com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response response = request.send();

    return Response.ok(response.getBody()).build();
}
```

The built URL looks like: https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=XXX_SECRET_XXX&name=Test_v1

I've also tried swapping the access_token after the params but same result.

Appreciate the any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved this by creating a object, serializing it, and adding it as a payload.

```
@POST
@Path("create_repo/{userId}/{projectId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createRepo(@PathParam("userId") String userId, @PathParam("projectId") String projectId) {

    // Setup collections
    User user = userCollection.findOneById(userId);
    ProjectDescription projectDescription = projectCollection.findOneById(projectId);

    // Build repository object from project description
    GithubRepository repository = new GithubRepository();
    repository.setName(projectDescription.getTitle());
    repository.setDescription(projectDescription.getDescription());

    // Serialize object
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = null;
    try {
        jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(repository);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Build request
    OAuthService service = createService().build();
    final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL + "/user/repos", service);
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.addPayload(jsonInString);

    // Sign and send request
    Token token = new Token(user.getGithubToken(), "secret");
    service.signRequest(token, request);
    request.send();

    return Response.status(201).build();
}
```

However, I'd still like to know where I went wrong with my first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Query string parameters are ignored in `POST` requests. That's why it worked when passing them in the request body.

From [GitHub's API Overview docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#parameters):

> #### Parameters
>
> Many API methods take optional parameters. For GET requests, any parameters not specified as a segment in the path can be passed as an HTTP query string parameter:
>
> `curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed"`
>
> In this example, the ‘vmg’ and ‘redcarpet’ values are provided for the `:owner` and `:repo` parameters in the path while `:state` is passed in the query string.
>
> For POST, PATCH, PUT, and DELETE requests, parameters not included in the URL should be encoded as JSON with a Content-Type of ‘application/json’:
>
> `$ curl -i -u username -d '{"scopes":["public_repo"]}' https://api.github.com/authorizations`